# Can I run multiple applications or containers for Docker images on a single AWS Beanstalk instance/cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Running each application or micro-service on its own Beanstalk cluster, with multiple VMs in each, seem very inefficient. Is there a way that multiple micro-services can be run on a single cluster, with Beanstalk being aware of them being separate entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like running a [**multicontainer Docker environment**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html) is a solution for you. Each of the microservices would run in a separate Docker container (which can then be multiplied). In this case, Elastic Beanstalk manages an ECS - Elastic Container Service - cluster for you (creation, task definitions and execution). If you want to have more control over everything, you can use the ECS service directly.